# Problems arise for negative values of $t$ when allowing the two-sided Laplace transform?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I am currently studying the textbook *An Introduction to Laplace Transforms and Fourier Series*, second edition, by Phil Dyke. Chapter **2.1 Real Functions** describes *Heaviside's unit step function* as follows:

> Sometimes, a function $F(t)$ represents a natural or engineering process that has no obvious starting value. Statisticians call this a *time series*. Although we shall not be considering $F(t)$ as stochastic, it is nevertheless worth introducing a way of "switching on" a function. Let us start by finding the Laplace transform of a step function the name of which pays homage to the pioneering electrical engineer Oliver Heaviside (1850 - 1925). The formal definition runs as follows.
>
> **Definition 2.1** *Heaviside's unit step function, or simply the unit step function, is defined as*
>
> $$H(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t < 0, \\ 1 & t \ge 0. \end{cases}$$
>
> Since $H(t)$ is precisely the same as $1$ for $t > 0$, the Laplace transform of $H(t)$ must be the same as the Laplace transform of $1$, i.e., $1/s$. The switching on of an arbitrary function is achieved simply by multiplying it by the standard function $H(t)$, so if $F(t)$ is given by the function shown in Fig. 2.1 and we multiply this function by the Heaviside unit step function $H(t)$ to obtain $H(t)F(t)$, Fig 2.2 results. Sometimes it is necessary to define what is called the *two sided* Laplace transform
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-st} F(t) \ dt,$$
>
> which makes a great deal of mathematical sense. However, the additional problems that arise by allowing negative values of $t$ are severe and limit the use of the two sided Laplace transform. For this reason, the two sided transform will not be pursued here.
>
> [image]

What are these "severe" problems that arise for the two-sided Laplace transform?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: That might be a bit of an exaggeration. If we have a causal system, $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal B$ will coincide, and if we have a non-causal system, $\mathcal L$ is not applicable. We have to keep track of the region of convergence though: $\mathcal B^{-1}[1/s] = H(t)$ if ROC is $\operatorname {Re} s > 0$ and $\mathcal B^{-1}[1/s] = -H(-t)$ if ROC is $\operatorname {Re} s < 0$.

Comment: @Maxim What is $\mathcal{B}$? And I'm assuming that $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform?

Comment: I used $\mathcal L$ for the unilateral Laplace transform and $\mathcal B$ for the bilateral Laplace transform.

Comment: @Maxim Ok, thanks for the clarification. How did you come to the conclusions for the values of $s$ for the region of convergence?